# Disabling HTTPS redirect in nginx.conf on Dokku

Tags: nginx, dokku

Gave this a good shot but it seems any documents online I find are relative to a certain use case, so for somebody with no previous nginx.conf experience it's a real pain!

I have a Ruby on Rails server on Dokku with the nginx.conf template shown below. What this currently does is redirect http:// requests to use https:// automatically. Though I need it to work on http:// as well without the redirect.

```
server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  server_name getbeambox.com yourhotspot.net www.getbeambox.com;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/beambox-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/beambox-error.log;

  return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;

}
server {
  listen      [::]:443 ssl spdy;
  listen      443 ssl spdy;
  server_name getbeambox.com yourhotspot.net www.getbeambox.com;
  server_name getbeambox.com yourhotspot.net www.getbeambox.com;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/beambox-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/beambox-error.log;

  ssl_certificate     /home/dokku/beambox/tls/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/dokku/beambox/tls/server.key;

  keepalive_timeout   70;
  add_header          Alternate-Protocol  443:npn-spdy/2;

  location    / {

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml  application/rss+xm$
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;

    proxy_pass  http://beambox-5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
  }
  include /home/dokku/beambox/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;
}

upstream beambox-5000 {

  server 172.17.0.3:5000;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Wouldn't ask if I wasn't truly stuck :)

Comment: You can serve `http` and `https` from a single `server` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/configuration/nginx/) is the document you're looking for, although it isn't super clear.

The first thing you need to do is create and commit a file in the root of your app's repo called `nginx.config.sigil`. Then you copy the content of [this file](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/master/plugins/nginx-vhosts/templates/nginx.conf.sigil) into it and make the necessary adjustments.

I am new to nginx as well, but I was able to find the line that was doing the redirect. Here is what my working file looks like:

```
{{ range $port_map := .PROXY_PORT_MAP | split " " }}
{{ $port_map_list := $port_map | split ":" }}
{{ $scheme := index $port_map_list 0 }}
{{ $listen_port := index $port_map_list 1 }}
{{ $upstream_port := index $port_map_list 2 }}

{{ if eq $scheme "http" }}
server {
  listen      [::]:{{ $listen_port }};
  listen      {{ $listen_port }};
  {{ if $.NOSSL_SERVER_NAME }}server_name {{ $.NOSSL_SERVER_NAME }}; {{ end }}
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/{{ $.APP }}-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/{{ $.APP }}-error.log;
  location    / {

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;

    proxy_pass  http://{{ $.APP }}-{{ $upstream_port }};
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
  }
  include {{ $.DOKKU_ROOT }}/{{ $.APP }}/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;
}
{{ else if eq $scheme "https"}}
server {
  listen      [::]:{{ $listen_port }} ssl {{ if eq $.SPDY_SUPPORTED "true" }}spdy{{ else if eq $.HTTP2_SUPPORTED "true" }}http2{{ end }};
  listen      {{ $listen_port }} ssl {{ if eq $.SPDY_SUPPORTED "true" }}spdy{{ else if eq $.HTTP2_SUPPORTED "true" }}http2{{ end }};
  {{ if $.SSL_SERVER_NAME }}server_name {{ $.SSL_SERVER_NAME }}; {{ end }}
  {{ if $.NOSSL_SERVER_NAME }}server_name {{ $.NOSSL_SERVER_NAME }}; {{ end }}
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/{{ $.APP }}-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/{{ $.APP }}-error.log;

  ssl_certificate     {{ $.APP_SSL_PATH }}/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key {{ $.APP_SSL_PATH }}/server.key;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

  keepalive_timeout   70;
  {{ if eq $.SPDY_SUPPORTED "true" }}add_header          Alternate-Protocol  {{ $.NGINX_SSL_PORT }}:npn-spdy/2;{{ end }}

  location    / {

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;

    proxy_pass  http://{{ $.APP }}-{{ $upstream_port }};
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
  }
  include {{ $.DOKKU_ROOT }}/{{ $.APP }}/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;
}
{{ end }}{{ end }}

{{ if $.DOKKU_APP_LISTENERS }}
{{ range $upstream_port := $.PROXY_UPSTREAM_PORTS | split " " }}
upstream {{ $.APP }}-{{ $upstream_port }} {
{{ range $listeners := $.DOKKU_APP_LISTENERS | split " " }}
{{ $listener_list := $listeners | split ":" }}
{{ $listener_ip := index $listener_list 0 }}
{{ $listener_port := index $listener_list 1 }}
  server {{ $listener_ip }}:{{ $upstream_port }};{{ end }}
}
{{ end }}{{ end }}
```